# Flying objects effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photomontage

I've been asked to create some kind of montage using Photoshop and the whole concept revolves around some kind of explosion. So I've gathered all of my elements and positioned them in their places, but somehow it doesn't feel like they're moving. I'm using a duplicated layer of each element and applying a path blur to simulate movement but so far it doesn't feels like it. Any good advice to solve a problem like this?

[image]

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think you must apply a motion blur with the right angle to each object.

Comment: The objects should be on fire. Or some smoke trail.

Comment: Yeah needs more cowbell!!!!!!! (Blur) `:)` the current blur looks more like a drop shadow on most of the elements. And I agree with @LeoNas on some sort of fire or charred appearance as well with smoke trails.

Comment: I think you should add debris, wreckage etc stuff and i think it's not a best platform to ask for suggestions. this platform help you to solve your problems but suggesting something in design is totally other thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blast is not violent enough to cause things to fly. And the flight directions cannot be in a plane, something must also fly towards the camera and something must be behind the flames and smoke. Generally there should be more pieces in the air. I tried to draw an example:

[image]